# Spectrum of Laplacian-like operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, elliptic-pde

Let $\kappa_1, \kappa_2>0$ be fixed.
Consider the unbounded operator $A: D(A) \rightarrow L^2(-1,1)\times\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
A\begin{bmatrix} y \\ h  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \partial_x^2 y - \kappa_1y\\ -\partial_xy(1) \end{bmatrix}
$$
with domain $D(A) \subset L^2(-1,1) \times \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
D(A) = \Big\{ \begin{bmatrix} y \\ h \end{bmatrix} \in H^2(-1,1)\times \mathbb{R} \colon y(-1) = 0,\, y(1) = -\kappa_2 h \Big\}.
$$
When considered as an unbounded operator on $L^2(-1,1)\times\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the canonical inner product, $A$ does not appear to be symmetric, hence it cannot be self-adjoint.

Edit: Thus up to my knowledge, checking that the resolvent is compact will imply that the spectrum of $A$ consists only of eigenvalues.

My question is the following:

> Can it be shown that the spectrum of $A$ consists only of real eigenvalues?

To this end, I imagine one needs to show that any point $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ is in the resolvent of $A$, but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: Have you tried to find the eigenvalues of $A$ by an explicit computation? Given the structure of the operator, this might not be impossible.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Yes, it's a lengthy computation but I managed to obtain an almost explicit form (basically they are like the Dirichlet Laplacian's + $O(k)$). But how can I guarantee that there is no essential spectrum?

Comment: The spectrum of operators with compact resolvent consists of eigenvalues (with finite multiplicity) only. That has nothing to do with self-adjointness.

Comment: Ok the theorem I know states this for self-adjoint operators. Do you mind giving me to a reference for non self-adjoint operators?

Comment: You can for instance find it in Corollary IV.1.19 of [Engel and Nagel: One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations (2000)] (but it is most likely also stated in much older references). Please beware, however, that "compact resolvent" includes by definition the property that the resolvent set of $A$ is non-empty; hence, it does not suffices to just observe that the domain of $A$ embeds compactly into the surrounding Banach space - one also needs to check that at least one complex number is in the resolvent set.

Comment: The resolvent is non-empty in this case because the elliptic problem associated to $A$ is uniquely solvable.

Comment: If u omit the BC at 1 there is a standard change of variables to make problems with advection term where advection is gradient if scalar into self adjoint problem...

Comment: @bgsk: So, can your question be considered settled, or is there any point that is still open?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Yes it's fine, I proved what I wanted.